# Why the CommitEdit won't trigger the cellValueChanged event when the cell was dirty?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have met a situation like this:

When a cell is clicked, The data source will be reset in the CellBeginEdit event, thus the cell is marked as dirty. Then CellContentClick event is triggered, the cell is marked as undirty(like below). As the point I thought this will trigger CellValueChanged event, but instead it went straight to CellEndEdit event. I checked CommitEdit function, it says system will commit the change to the data cache. I thought this will trigger a cell value changed event, but this didn't. Can anyone please elaborate a little bit on this? Thanks very much!

```
void gridRow_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (gridRow.IsCurrentCellDirty)//First this is dirty
        {
            gridRow.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }// After Commit, this is undirty
    }
```

Comment: Did the cell value really change (or only the cell state) ? Else, the `CellValueChanged` event won't trigger.

Comment: Hi Bioukh, the cell value changed but still not trigger the cellValueChanged event

Comment: What is the data type of the cell value ?